# Create Scala case classes for SCIO type safe read/write dynamically

Tags: scala, google-bigquery, reflection, apache-beam, spotify-scio

I'm trying to generate Scala classes dynamically, which then should be used as safe types in SCIO read/write [to/from GCP BigQuery](https://spotify.github.io/scio/io/BigQuery.html#using-type-safe-bigquery).

Target example:

```
import com.spotify.scio.bigquery._
import com.spotify.scio.bigquery.types.BigQueryType

@BigQueryType.fromTable("dataset.SOURCE_TABLE")
class SOURCE_TABLE

@BigQueryType.toTable
case class TARGET_TABLE(id: String, name: String, desc: String)

def main(cmdlineArgs: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val (sc, args) = ContextAndArgs(cmdlineArgs)
  sc.typedBigQuery[SOURCE_TABLE]()  // Read from BQ
    .map( row => transformation(row) ) // Transform -> SCollection[TARGET_TABLE]
    .saveAsTypedBigQueryTable(Table.Spec(args("TARGET_TABLE")))  // save to BQ
  sc.run()
  ()
}
```

As as input there are dataset, SOURCE_TABLE, TARGET_TABLE, list of target fields, so I can build up a string source of generated classes. All these values are retrieved dynamically from other 3rd party (json, xml, etc. ) and can be mutable by every execution.

So, the source of generated classes can be presented as:

```
val sourceString =
  s"""
     |import com.spotify.scio.bigquery.types.BigQueryType
     |
     |@BigQuery.fromTable("$dataset.$SOURCE_TABLE")
     |class $SOURCE_TABLE
     |
   """.stripMargin

val targetString =
  s"""
     |import com.spotify.scio.bigquery.types.BigQueryType
     |
     |@BigQueryType.toTable
     |case class $TARGET_TABLE($fieldDefinitions)
   """.stripMargin
```

These sources are considered to be translated to classes, which types are required for SCIO BigQuery I/O.

Scala version: 2.12.17

I tried to use Scala runtime Mirror and Toolbox (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39157685/4726740), from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39139732/4726740), etc.). But all variants throw the same error: ***enable macro paradise (2.12) or -Ymacro-annotations  (2.13) to expand macro annotations*** It's obvious that the Toolbox's internal compiler doesn't see the *build.sbt* settings:

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.1" cross CrossVersion.full)
```

Besides that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57964879/how-to-compile-and-run-scala-code-programmatically) mentioned that Toolbox is not intended for such complex thing.

So, I decided to apply an approach using the package `scala.tools.nsc` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56923075/4726740). But it throws the same error about the lack of macro annotations.

Thus the main question: is there any chance to add required compiler plugin settings to `scala.tools.nsc.{Global, Settings}` or to apply any other approach to generate such annotated classes dynamically?

```
def compileCode(sources: List[String], classpathDirectories: List[AbstractFile], outputDirectory: AbstractFile): Unit = {
  val settings = new Settings
  classpathDirectories.foreach(dir => settings.classpath.prepend(dir.toString))
  settings.outputDirs.setSingleOutput(outputDirectory)
  settings.usejavacp.value = true
  //*****
  // Add macros paradise compiler plugin?
  //*****
  val global = new Global(settings)
  val files = sources.zipWithIndex.map { case (code, i) => new BatchSourceFile(s"(inline-$i)", code) }
  (new global.Run).compileSources(files)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch on the paradise plugin for toolbox by feeding corresponding command-line option

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
val rm = runtime.currentMirror

val tb = rm.mkToolBox(options = "-Xplugin:/path/to/.cache/coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalamacros/paradise_2.12.18/2.1.1/paradise_2.12.18-2.1.1.jar")
```

in Scala 2.12 or

```scala
val tb = rm.mkToolBox(options = "-Ymacro-annotations")
```

in Scala 2.13.

If you prefer actual compiler over toolbox then you can feed the option in the following way

```scala
settings.plugin.value = List("/path/to/.cache/coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalamacros/paradise_2.12.18/2.1.1/paradise_2.12.18-2.1.1.jar")
```

in Scala 2.12 or

```scala
settings.YmacroAnnotations.value = true
```

in Scala 2.13.

Comment: Thanks. It works good for compiler approach. Meanwhile, I have found also an alternative option for it from [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24062680/4726740): `settings.processArgumentString("-Xplugin:/path/to/paradise.jar -Xplugin-require:macroparadise")` , but I consider your `settings.plugin.value` is more explicit.

Regarding the Toolbox approach. It resolves the macros exceptions, but then I'm getting another exception: `... reflective compilation has failed: No TypeTag available for __wrapper$1$7....__wrapper$1$7....SOURCE_TABLE.SOURCE_TABLE`

Comment: @kolya_metallist Is compiler approach enough for you? Or are interested in toolbox approach as well? In order to investigate `No TypeTag available` I need reproduction.

Comment: thanks. At this moment the compiler is enough, I continue attempts to apply it for SCIO.